# Lowdb count each string in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, optimization, lodash

I'm trying to count the number of string in an array of objects using lowdb.

Here is a sample of my objects:

```
{
  "tags": [
    "test",
    "test2"
  ]
},
{
  "tags": [
    "test",
    "test3"
  ]
}
```

I'd like to get this:

```
{
  test: 2,
  test2: 1,
  test3: 1
}
```

I have successfully get this doing like this:

```
_.each(selectAll().value(), (bookmark) => {
    if (bookmark.tags.length > 0) {
        _.each(bookmark.tags, (bookmarksTags) => {
            if (!(bookmarksTags in tags)) {
                tags[bookmarksTags] = 0
            }

            tags[bookmarksTags]++
        })
    }
})
```

It works but... it's ugly and I don't like it. Do you know a better and proper Lodash's way to do this?

Comment: `if (bookmark.tags.length > 0)` is unnecessary

Comment: You're right. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` and `forEach()` with plain javascript.

```js
var data = [{"tags":["test","test2"]},{"tags":["test","test3"]}]

var result = data.reduce(function(r, e) {
  return (e.tags.forEach(e => r[e] = (r[e] || 0) + 1)), r
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Elegant way to do it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One way using Lodash:

```
_.countBy(_.flatMap(arr,'tags'))
```

Where `arr` is the source array

```js
var o = [{  "tags": [    "test",    "test2"  ]},{  "tags": [    "test",    "test3"  ]}];

console.log(_.countBy(_.flatMap(o,'tags')));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you to show me the Lodash way! I'll try to understand better how it works.